# how to resolve Link error with BaseGameUtility when building Android project

Tags: android

I am trying to use Google Play Games Services with my android project. I have followed instructions as both seen on the official documentation and here as well: http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u1070589/blog/?p=202

Both libraries BaseGameUtils and google-play-services_lib are added and referenced by my project. BaseGameUtils references google-play-services_lib.

All boxes are checked under Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export.

I receive the following error when attempting to run:
Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;' failed

I don't understand the issue. I have followed the instructions exactly. And retried several times.

Any ideas?

Comment: I followed the instructions several more times and I am getting this error now: The type com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$OnConnectionFailedListener cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go into the Java Build Path and remove BaseGameUtils and google-play-services_lib from there.

Also to remove another error I had to go into the libraries section and add the two jars (basegameutils.jar and google-play-services.jar.)

I'm not sure why this last part was nowhere in the instructions but this fixed the problem.